# Hide Asymptote Play Button

Tags: graphics, animations, asymptote

How do I hide the annoying play button that appears whenever I do 3D graphics with `asymptote`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
import three;

size(200);
currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,3);

draw(unitsphere,green,render(compression=Zero,merge=true));
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to keep the interactive 3d capabilities? If not, just put `settings.prc=false;` for the first line of your `asy` environment.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Awesome. At the moment I don't care about keeping the interactive capabilities, but I could imagine wanting to keep them but hiding the play but [e.g., so that people a simple pdf can view the image without a play button]. Do you know if this is doable? Also, what is `prc`?

Comment: PRC is interactive 3D content. That is why the playbutton is there. Click it and you will see.

Comment: @AlexG That I understand, but why is it called PRC?

Comment: PRC is an interactive 3D file format developped by Adobe that can be rendered in Adobe Reader. Asymptote is one of the few Open-Source projects that can produce PRC. And LaTeX package `media9` is used to embed it into LaTeX generated PDF documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{noplaybutton}{media9}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
import three;

size(200);
currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,3);

draw(unitsphere,green,render(compression=Zero,merge=true));
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

does the trick, but keep in mind that the unaware reader of a PDF could miss the interactive content.

Comment: Is there a way to set up the play button to show only if the reader is using Adobe Reader? For e.g. Apple Preview, the play button is not only annoying but also misleading.

Comment: @CharlesStaats. Difficult. The reader brand would need to be detected somehow in order decide whether or not to enable the button. This requires JavaScript...

Comment: @CharlesStaats: With the next version 0.40, the play button, if not disabled as explained above, will be shown only in Adobe Reader.

Comment: After reading your last comment, I wished I could upvote this answer more than once. Then I realized that, in a sense, I can. But not for 23 hours.

Comment: @CharlesStaats It is implemented using OCGs (aka PDF layers). The button layer is disabled by default and enabled in Adobe Reader using JavaScript. This works in `pdflatex`, `dvipdfmx` and `xelatex` generated PDFs. The `dvips` driver doesn't work for `ps2pdf` because the required specials are not implemented in Ghostscript. But it works with Acrobat or Distiller, although button transparency is lost for some reason.

Comment: @AlexG, Is there a way to show the button but make it more subtle? (e.g. smaller and at the bottom right curve). My point is that both the extremely big play button and no button at all are both "bad" extremes. Also, showing a subtle button (in non-Acrobat reader) can remind the user that there is content in there (but not raise the audience to the question "why that huge PLAY symbol on top of that image that never played"). Example (unintrusive play at bottom) : http://tinyurl.com/lnzcve5

Comment: @alfC: Thank you for the suggestion. I will think about it.

Comment: @AlexG, do you know if it is possible to pass this option to (standalone) Asymptote (`asy`) so that it doesn't generate the play button. I tried adding `texpreamble("\PassOptionsToPackage{noplaybutton}{media9}");` to the top of the `asy` program.

Comment: @alfC And does it work? If not, run asy with the `-k` or `--keep` option. This keeps intermediate files. In of the `*.tex` files, you can add `, noplaybutton` to the option list of `\includemedia`.

Comment: @AlexG, no it didn't work, I think the preamble is only for extracting paths for labels but not for the final `tex`. But your suggestion (with `--keep`) worked, although it requires some manual work.