# media9: Locally enable or disable play button

Tags: media9

Is there an existing way (without updating the media9 package) to enable or disable the play button after the package is loaded? The current motivation is [to disable the play button for only some versions of `media9`](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/e5ce0dd9/#fb81), but it could also be used to enable the button for some images but not others, or to switch between `fancy` and `plain`.

(Incidentally, I like the look of the button used in version 0.43 of the documentation; it's much closer to the ideal of being prominent but not annoying. But I also think it would be nice if it did not print, much like the "red boxes" produced by `hyperref`.)

Comment: Doesn't the `noplaybutton` work as an option to the `includemedia` command? (BTW, Making the play button less intrusive was a feature request I put here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157405/1871 and @AlexG has been incredibly helpful and responsive)

Comment: BTW, if @AlexG is around, the manual of version 0.43 (I opened to check the new play button) makes Acrobat 9.4.1 Linux to crash in page 18. (Maybe it is because a flash swf player incompatible with 9.4.1 is used) The rest of the manual seems to render well including the beautiful 3D examples.

Comment: @alfC: I considered making this a comment to that excellent answer--I agree that AlexG has been incredible about it (in fact I awarded him a bounty for it). I decided that if he were going to answer this question, he should have the chance to receive additional upvotes for it.

Comment: The question title should be reformulated: "Prevent the play button from being printed". As for locally enabling or disabling it or choosing a look, this is already possible by using one of `playbutton=none|fancy|plain` with `\includemedia`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The play button can be locally enabled or disabled or given another look with one of `playbutton=none|fancy|plain` in the options argument of `\includemedia`.

Currently, the play button is printed when printing to paper or file from within AR. This will change in the next version (0.44) of `media9`.

Comment: @Charles: Just uploaded v. 0.44 to CTAN.